# How does rpart in R differ from SPSS classification trees?

Tags: classification, cart

I am using rpart in R for some decision trees. I decided to check the results in SPSS - classification - trees, and different variables were selected.

In rpart, I'm using method="class" and the default control parameters.
In SPSS, I went with CRT, Gini and the same controls.

I get different splits.

Does anyone know exactly which algorithms are being used by SPSS and rpart?

Comment: For SPSS, see SPSS Tree Algorithms (just google). "CRT" is CRT (=CART) algorithm.

Comment: @ttnphns That's precisely my point. SPSS' crt claims to implement Breiman et al CART algorithm, as does rpart - according to Therneau's vignette. They should give the same results.

Comment: Have you checked rpart.control default settings? There are several parameters that could differ, leading to different splits.

Comment: @katya Yes, I looked at that, and that could be the reason. Unfortunately, tweaking rpart.control and the corresponding screens in SPSS sill did not give me the same results. One trouble is that the cross-validation in rpart rests upon random selections of the data and you can get different answers on different runs.